# Sed command to replace "(double quote) to &quot; and ' (single quote) to &apos; in all xml tag value in a file

Tags: linux, sed, command-line, pattern-matching

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document>
    <InnerDoc>
        <GrpHdr>
            <MsgId>aaa.xml</MsgId>
            <CreDtTm>2023-08-15T13:35:33.0Z</CreDtTm>
            <MsgRcpt>
                    <Id  value="111">
                    <OrgId>
                        <Othr>
                            <Id>asa-"-as'#</Id>
                        </Othr>
                    </OrgId>
                </Id>
            </MsgRcpt>
            <tag1 info = "AddInf1">Report Map = PRIOR DAY BALTRAN INCREMENTAL " - '</tag1>
            <tag2 info = "AddInf2">Report Map =  " - '</tag1>
        </GrpHdr>
    </InnerDoc>
</Document>
```

For the above xml I need to replace all `"` (double quote) to `&quot;` and `'` (single quote) to `&apos;`
for eg:  `<tag1 info = "AddInf1">Report Map = PRIOR DAY BALTRAN INCREMENTAL &quot; - &apos</tag1>`
It should replace for text only in xml tag value.So, It should match text between pattern `>` and `<`. could you please suggest correct sed command for this?

I tried sed command to replace but it's replacing all. I need to do pattern match and consider only text within `>` and `<` for replacing

Comment: Mike Farah's [yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) will get you most of the way with just `yq -p xml -o xml . <in.xml >out.xml` (it encodes to `&#34;` and `&#39;` rather than quot and apos)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using GNU awk for multi-char `RS` and `RT`:

```
$ awk -v RS='>[^<]+<' -v ORS= '{
    gsub(/"/,"\\&quot;",RT)
    gsub(/\047/,"\\&apos;",RT)
    print $0 RT
}' file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document>
    <InnerDoc>
        <GrpHdr>
            <MsgId>aaa.xml</MsgId>
            <CreDtTm>2023-08-15T13:35:33.0Z</CreDtTm>
            <MsgRcpt>
                    <Id  value="111">
                    <OrgId>
                        <Othr>
                            <Id>asa-&quot;-as&apos;#</Id>
                        </Othr>
                    </OrgId>
                </Id>
            </MsgRcpt>
            <tag1 info = "AddInf1">Report Map = PRIOR DAY BALTRAN INCREMENTAL &quot; - &apos;</tag1>
            <tag2 info = "AddInf2">Report Map =  &quot; - &apos;</tag1>
        </GrpHdr>
    </InnerDoc>
</Document>
```

It's obviously fragile as `>` or `<` might appear in text or within tag attributes.

Answer (score 0):

As typed in a bash terminal:

```
sed -E ':a s/(>[^"]*)"(.*<)/\1'\''\2/;ta' file
```

An XML parser might be more appropriate, but sed can do it, too:

- use `-E` for extended regex (ERE) to get capture groups w/o backslash

  - "Capture groups" here are `( )` on the match side and `\1` and `\2` on the replacement side of the `s///` substitution
- `:a` and `ta`: loop to label a until substitution fails
- `s/(>[^"]*)"(.*<)/\1'\2/` --> substitution *without* shell quoting/escaping

  - replace `"` with `'` when between `> <`
  - Terminal input is as above: `':a s/(>[^"]*)"(.*<)/\1'\''\2/;ta'` -- *may have to adapt quoting or escaping for scripting*
  - very dependent on HTML structured like in question, which is why an XML parser would be better than sed

Comment: That changes `"`s to `'`s in the text, which isn't what the OP is trying to do, best I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E ':a;s/(>[^'\''<]*)'\''/\1\&apos;/;ta;s/(>[^"<]*)"/\1\&quot;/;ta' file
```

Match a `>`, followed by zero or more non `'`'s or `<`'s, followed by `'`, replace the `'` by `&apos;` and repeat.

Match a `>`, followed by zero or more non `"`'s or `<`'s, followed by `"`, replace the `"` by `&quot;` and repeat.