# grep command to find the presence of either quote(") or apostrophe(') in the xml tag value of the file

Tags: regex, xml, command-line, grep

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <Document>
    <InnerDoc>
        <GrpHdr>
            <MsgId>aaa.xml</MsgId>
            <CreDtTm>2023-08-15T13:35:33.0Z</CreDtTm>
            <MsgRcpt>
                    <Id  value="111">
                    <OrgId>
                        <Othr>
                            <Id>asa-"-as'#</Id>
                        </Othr>
                    </OrgId>
                </Id>
            </MsgRcpt>
            <tag1 info = "AddInf1">Report Map = PRIOR DAY BALTRAN INCREMENTAL " - '</tag1>
            <tag2 info = "AddInf2">Report Map =  " - '</tag1>
        </GrpHdr>
    </InnerDoc>
</Document>
```

In the above XML I need to find whether there is at least one occurrence of either quote (`"`) or apostrophe (`'`) in the XML tag value only.

For example, in

```
<tag1 info = "AddInf1">Report Map = PRIOR DAY BALTRAN INCREMENTAL " - '</tag1>
```

`grep` should evaluate the string between `>` and `<` only.

I tried a simple special char search. But it is searching the double quotes of non-XML tag values such as in the header `version="1.0"`. I don't need that, and want to avoid it.

Comment: Any attempt to build this kind of XML parsing with grep & related tools will miss some corner case somewhere, so it's better to use tools that handle XML natively. `xmllint` is often used for this. You could easily write a XPath expression to find any text element containing either character. Also: ask yourself if you care about the specific characters/bytes or if you also want to match `&quot;` and `&#x22;` which represent the same content in XML.

Comment: For quick and dirty grepping, try `grep -Po "(?<=>)[^<>'\"]*[\"'][^<>]*(?=<" file.xml`

Comment: I wish people weren't so quick to close these types of question. Not everyone has or can install an XML (or YAML or JSON or whatever) parser and then we have to make do with whatever tools we do have, usually just (possibly GNU variants of) the mandatory POSIX tools sed, grep, awk, etc.

Comment: Assuming you don't have an XML parser handy, [the answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77545520/1745001) which shows how to **replace** single or double quotes gives you a **big** clue as to how to do what you're asking for now which is just to **find** those quotes.

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/beingunresponsive 
https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joachim Sauer's comment is correct - for example, even the simplest invocation on your test input yields this:

```
$: xmllint file
file:17: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: tag2 line 17 and tag1
            <tag2 info = "AddInf2">Report Map =  " - '</tag1>
                                                             ^
```

And it will make it easier to process escape codes.

With his much-appreciated assist:

```
$: xmllint --xpath "//text()[contains(.,'\"') or contains(., \"'\")]" file
asa-"-as'#Double only: " Single only: '
```

Still trying to figure a way to get the newlines and maybe line numbers.

That said, what you really want is to find records with single or double quotes in that value space.

```
$: grep -n $'>[^<]*[\'"][^<]*<' file
11:                            <Id>asa-"-as'#</Id>
16:            <tag1 info = "AddInf1">Report Map = PRIOR DAY BALTRAN INCREMENTAL " - '</tag1>
17:            <tag2 info = "AddInf2">Report Map =  " - '</tag1>
```

This is going to break if the tag-delimiting characters (`<` & `>`) are *embedded* in the value space, such as `&lt;` or in a quoted string (which is questionable XML, anyway.)

Note the `$'...'` construct is a Bash-ism. If that's unavailable you may need a more complicated bit of creative cross-quoting to get both correctly.

```
$: grep -n '>[^<]*["'"'][^<]*<" file
11:                            <Id>asa-"-as'#</Id>
16:            <tag1 info = "AddInf1">Double only: " </tag1>
17:            <tag2 info = "AddInf2">Single only: ' </tag1>

$: grep -n '>[^<]*['"'"'"][^<]*<' file
11:                            <Id>asa-"-as'#</Id>
16:            <tag1 info = "AddInf1">Double only: " </tag1>
17:            <tag2 info = "AddInf2">Single only: ' </tag1>
```

Comment: The XPath expression `//text()[contains(.,'"')]` would return text that contains `"`.

Comment: Excellent. Add the single quote and we're there!

Comment: `//text()[contains(.,'"') or contains(., "'")]`

Comment: How do we get it to add newlines? It's smashing it all together.

Answer (score 0):

You'd be much better off using an XML-parser, like [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel). [As has been repeated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454) [here countless](https://stackoverflow.com/q/590747) [times already](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6751105); it's a really bad idea to use regex to parse XML. You wouldn't use a fork to eat soup either, now would you?

*(Despite a missing [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) or [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) tag, I'm going to assume you're on Unix.)*

First of all...

```
$ xidel -s --input-format=xml-strict input.xml -e .
Error:
In '' (line 17 pos 57): Unmatching element end tag (expected "</tag2>")
```

After this has been fixed...

```
$ xidel -s input.xml -e '//text()[contains(.,"""") or contains(.,"'\''")]'
$ xidel -s input.xml -e '//text()[contains(.,"&quot;") or contains(.,"&apos;")]'
$ xidel -s input.xml -e '//text()[matches(.,"[""'\'']")]'
$ xidel -s input.xml -e '//text()[matches(.,"[&quot;&apos;]")]'
asa-"-as'#
Report Map = PRIOR DAY BALTRAN INCREMENTAL " - '
Report Map =  " - '
```

Though all 4 commands yield the same output, I'd prefer the last one for being the shortest and most readable.

---

If you want a more similar output as Paul Hodges posted in his answer (including line numbers), then this can be done with a little more effort:

```
$ xidel -s input.xml -e '
  for $txt in //text()[matches(.,"[&quot;&apos;]")]
  for $line at $i in x:lines($raw)
  where matches($line,$txt)
  return
  `{$i}: {$txt}`
'
11: asa-"-as'#
16: Report Map = PRIOR DAY BALTRAN INCREMENTAL " - '
17: Report Map =  " - '
```

or

```
$ xidel -s input.xml -e '
  for $txt in //text()[matches(.,"[&quot;&apos;]")]
  for $line at $i in x:lines($raw)
  where matches($line,$txt)
  return
  `{$i}: {$line}`
'
11:                             <Id>asa-"-as'#</Id>
16:             <tag1 info = "AddInf1">Report Map = PRIOR DAY BALTRAN INCREMENTAL " - '</tag1>
17:             <tag2 info = "AddInf2">Report Map =  " - '</tag2>
```